# Globbing to check whether files with different file extension exist

Tags: regex, bash, glob

I'm writing a conditional expression to check whether files a set of required extensions do exist or not. This looks like the following:

```
if [ ! -f "${FILE}.ext1" ] || [ ! -f "${FILE}.ext2" ] || [ ! -f "${FILE}.ext3" ]; then
        echo "Error: missing extensions"
        exit
fi
```

I was trying to do so by using a more simpler globbing pattern such as:

```
if [ ! -f "${FILE}.{ext1,ext2,ext3}" ]; then ...
```

But this does not work (it does if I use it with a different command like `ls -l`). Where is the error? Is there an alternative way to simplify the above conditional expression?

Comment: This will help [`alternation in bash glob`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50220/using-or-patterns-in-shell-wildcards)

Comment: if statements can not take multiple expressions, return error too many expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here:

1. The wildcard and [brace expansion](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#EXPANSION) expressions may not be enclosed by quotes.
2. The `test -f` command can't handle multiple arguments.

A working solution is this:

```
for F in "${FILE}."{ext1,ext2,ext3}; do
    if [ ! -f "${F}" ]; then
        echo "not found: ${F}"
    fi
done
```

Also make sure you're using `#!/bin/bash` as shebang at top of the script, as the brace expansion is a *bashism*, and the script won't be portable to other shells.